# It looks like JSON.stringify() executes twice

Tags: javascript, json

If I run `JSON.stringify(["hello"])` in the console the output is as expected:

```
<- "["hello"]"
```

If I run it twice like `JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(["hello"]))` it results into the following as expected:

```
<- ""[\"hello\"]""
```

Now I was trying the same thing on [this page](http://www.shz.de). If I run `JSON.stringify(["hello"])` in the console it returns the second example´s result right away.

```
<- ""[\"hello\"]""
```

I have no idea what is happening there. It looks like someone is overwriting the native `JSON.stringify` function. If so, how can I restore that?

Comment: *"Now I was trying the same thing on this page."* Always put all relevant code and markup **in** the question. Don't expect people to visit random links. Links rot, making the question and answers useless to anyone else in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I see your point, but I have absolutely no idea what causes this behavior. And said page includes dozens of external Javascripts. So my question is merely if there are known frameworks out there that alter the `JSON.stringify` function and if I can restore the native functionality somehow?

Comment: @Amberlamps, on that page `JSON.stringify.toString()` still displays `[native code]`, so it does not look like it was overriden. Something else must be going on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I saw that, too. That is even weirder, right?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Ugh, that's always no fun. It'll be a matter of remove, remove, remove until the problem stops happening. Or alternately, create a new page, then add, add, add until it starts happening. :-) It's always hard to know which to start with (removing or adding) and I always get to the end of the process and think I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that something is adding `String.prototype.toJSON` and `Array.prototype.toJSON`. If I do this in the console on your page:

```
String.prototype.toJSON.toString()
```

I get

```
"function (){return this.inspect(true)}"
```

And similarly

```
Array.prototype.toJSON.toString()
```

gives me

```
"function (){var c=[];this.each(function(a){var b=Object.toJSON(a);if(!Object.isUndefined(b))c.push(b)});return'['+c.join(', ')+']'}"
```

`JSON.stringify` will look first to an object to see if it has a `toJSON` and, if so, will use it to get the JSON for that object ([spec link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3)). I suspect the implementation being added is not happily coexisting with the browser's `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Isn´t that the perfect example why you should not mess with the prototypes of the native Javascript objects?

Comment: @Amberlamps: It's a pretty good one, yeah. :-) (I have to admit I still do it in app code. It's just too handy. I'm really leery of doing it *in libraries*, though, preferring the jQuery approach over the PrototypeJS approach.)